# Change value of baseurl in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

How to change baseurl value in joomla?

```
echo $this->baseurl
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You shouldn't need to change the baseurl value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseurl is automatic function of joomla..

defined at

`/templates/ja_purity/ja_templatetools.php -> line 165`

If you clarify your problem, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: This is only valid if you are using the JA Purity template. Baseurl comes from the JDocumentHTML or JView objects depending on where it is being called.

Comment: @BrentFriar Do you know where the baseurl is being created in joomla 3.0? I want to change the http to https

Comment: @Rikesh Could you please take a look at my htacces? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781674/apache-loads-relative-urls-as-http-when-using-https

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->baseurl = 'yourvalue_';
```