# where is $this->baseurl defined in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

On my joomla website I'm using `echo $this->baseurl;` but it returns the url containing "/index.php". I want to change this to remove "/index.php" from `baseurl`. But I cannot find the definition line of `$this->baseurl;`.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137080/change-value-of-baseurl-in-joomla) but this is based on the template of the question owner and in my template there isn't something like this.

Suggestions very appreciated :)

Comment: It's better to ask Joomla questions on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Answered here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/4866/12352