# Apache loads relative URLS as HTTP when using HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I am trying to use SSL on my website, but the recources that have a relative URL load as http:// even when the page is using https://

This is my .htacces

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=http [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^tacticalghillies.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tacticalghillies.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

What am I screwing up?

Comment: With `RewriteEngine on` ?

Comment: Ah this is an old version sorry, RewriteEngine is on actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to understand all your "code".

I think you can add in the beginning :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This "code" is the mess joomla gives you, when I add the rule it creates a redirect loop

Comment: Try with the `[R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: https://www.tacticalghillies.nl/ Same errors, maybe I should delete all the joomla trash and redirect everything to index.php?

Comment: You add the new rule just below `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: Without the recources giving errors for non-https links in the console?

Comment: Yes... with errors (sorry!). But I can see in your html page `<base href="http://www.tacticalghillies.nl/"/>` the browser use that, and show error message...

Comment: I was affraid that was the problem, going to have to break that out of joomla somewhere then thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess with HTACCESS (you can easily screw up your SEF URLS is you do) just use the Joomla global configuration and force SSL to always on. Any Joomla page will automatically use SSL if you turn on the setting.